# Why isn't my CCParticleSystem Showing up Cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

This might be related not to the particle system but more on layering, but... i have the following code for the particle system:

```
CCParticleExplosion *explosion = [[CCParticleExplosion alloc] init];
explosion.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"blah.png"];
explosion.position = ccp(100,100);
[explosion setAutoRemoveOnFinish:YES];
[explosion setTotalParticles:10];
[self addChild:explosion];
[explosion autorelease];
```

and it renders fine if i stick that code in like a "HelloWorld" scene. However, if i put the code under a CCLayer, and i add that CCLayer to the "HelloWorld" scene, the particles don't show up. Why is that? (i see the CCLayer just fine)

the only noticeable difference is that in my "HelloWorld" scene, i have a "world" object. and i even tried to add in `[self scheduleUpdate]` in my CCLayer.

in my CCLayer, i also have a blank update. am i supposed to do something here?

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta{

}
```

any help, including good general practice (esp memory management) would be greatly appreciated. (just starting out cocos/iOS dev) Thanks!!

Comment: check the Z position of your layer on scene .. it might hide your ccparticle system

Answer (score 1):

Check that:

- texture isn't nil
- texture isn't too big (max 512x512)
- texture has power of two dimensions (4, 8, 16, 32, etc)
- duration is positive (otherwise it would auto remove the effect)
- self.visible == YES
- (self.position + explosion.position) == somewhere on the screen (explosion's position is added to self's position since its position is relative to its parent)